# Celery auto reload on ANY changes

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I could make celery reload itself automatically when there is changes on modules in `CELERY_IMPORTS` in `settings.py`.

I tried to give mother modules to detect changes even on child modules but it did not detect changes in child modules. That make me understand that detecting is not done recursively by celery. I searched it in the documentation but I did not meet any response for my problem.

It is really bothering me to add everything related celery part of my project to `CELERY_IMPORTS` to detect changes.

Is there a way to tell celery that "auto reload yourself when there is any changes in anywhere of project".

Thank You!

Comment: The `--autoreload` option has been deprecated and is not valid anymore in new Celery. The best is really to send a broadcast message to shut down the agent, and have something on top such as `supervisord` to restart the agent automatically. I use that in production with remote agents downloading a package from the web application at startup time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django and Celery - re-loading code into Celery after a change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919166/django-and-celery-re-loading-code-into-celery-after-a-change)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can manually include additional modules with `-I|--include`. Combine this with GNU tools like `find` and `awk` and you'll be able to find all `.py` files and include them.

```
$ celery -A app worker --autoreload --include=$(find . -name "*.py" -type f | awk '{sub("\./",""); gsub("/", "."); sub(".py",""); print}' ORS=',' | sed 's/.$//')
```

Lets explain it:

```
find . -name "*.py" -type f
```

`find` searches recursively for all files containing `.py`. The output looks something like this:

```
./app.py
./some_package/foopy
./some_package/bar.py
```

Then:

```
awk '{sub("\./",""); gsub("/", "."); sub(".py",""); print}' ORS=','
```

This line takes output of `find` as input and removes all occurences of `./`. Then it replaces all `/` with a `.`. The last `sub()` removes replaces `.py` with an empty string. `ORS` replaces all newlines with `,`. This outputs:

```
app,some_package.foo,some_package.bar,
```

The last command, `sed` removes the last `,`.

So the command that is being executed looks like:

```
$ celery -A app worker --autoreload --include=app,some_package.foo,some_package.bar
```

If you have a `virtualenv` inside your source you can exclude it by adding `-path .path_to_your_env -prune -o`:

```
$ celery -A app worker --autoreload --include=$(find . -path .path_to_your_env -prune -o -name "*.py" -type f | awk '{sub("\./",""); gsub("/", "."); sub(".py",""); print}' ORS=',' | sed 's/.$//')
```

Comment: You'd probably want to use `gsub("/", ".");` instead of `sub("/", ".");` in the *awk* part in order to replace all slashes in the file name?

Comment: If one of your modules contains `*py` (that is, any character followed by `py`) those three characters will be stripped from the module name (in my case mangling "copy_thing" to "c_thing"). To fix it update `sub(".py", "")` to `sub("\\.py$")`.

Comment: Seems that from version `4.0` on, the `--autoreload` functionality [has been removed](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html?highlight=autoreload#features-removed-for-lack-of-funding) :(

Comment: not valid anymore (v4+)
refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74767054/3065198

Answer (score 40):

Celery `--autoreload` doesn't work and it is [deprecated](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1658).

Since you are using django, you can write a management command for that. 
Django has autoreload utility which is used by runserver to restart WSGI server when code changes.

The same functionality can be used to reload celery workers. Create a seperate management command called celery. Write a function to kill existing worker and start a new worker. Now hook this function to autoreload as follows.

```
import shlex
import subprocess

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.utils import autoreload


def restart_celery():
    cmd = 'pkill celery'
    subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
    cmd = 'celery worker -l info -A foo'
    subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('Starting celery worker with autoreload...')

        # For Django>=2.2
        autoreload.run_with_reloader(restart_celery) 

        # For django<2.1
        # autoreload.main(restart_celery)
```

Now you can run celery worker with `python manage.py celery` which will autoreload when codebase changes.

This is only for development purposes and do not use it in production. Code taken from my [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43929298/2698552).

Comment: How can I run only one celery worker? This example runs two instances.

Comment: This code doesn't really reloads worker for me because it only tracks python files loaded by command not by worker.

Comment: It should track all the files which are part of django project as auto reload is handled by django. If it is not part django, it won't reload.

Comment: @MikeS The first call should kill all the previous celery instances, just tested

Comment: Sadly, this elegant solution did not work for me... the celery *did* restart on code update... but the changes would **not** be taken in account after the restart :((( The watchdog alternative worked as intended for me.

Comment: It works pretty well, but if a file contains a syntax error it crashes instead of waiting to reload the fixed file. The runserver command somehow can handle this. Simply catching `SyntaxError` in the command doesn't work.

Comment: I am running my application in docker, so pkill was not available.  But I was able to achieve the same with psutil (pip install psutil) and then `for proc in psutil.process_iter(): if proc.name() == 'celery': proc.terminate()`

Answer (score 25):

You can use watchmedo

```
pip install watchdog
```

Start celery worker indirectly via watchmedo

```
watchmedo auto-restart --directory=./ --pattern=*.py --recursive -- celery worker --app=worker.app --concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO
```

[More detailed](https://www.distributedpython.com/2019/04/23/celery-reload/)

Comment: broken on windows

Comment: Perhaps the directory=./ parameter should be written differently on windows

Comment: I don't think it's related to that, I get `AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'setsid'` as error.

Comment: You might as well just install the utility if all you need is to use it from the cli: `pip install -U 'watchdog[watchmedo]'`

Comment: @AlexTT I got this error. The support for this usage was removed in Celery 5.0. Instead you should use `-A` as a global option:
celery -A celeryapp worker <...>
I have answered it below

Comment: I am using watchmedo to refresh celery on every reload.  It leaves a lot of Zombie processes.   anyone else facing similar issue?

Answer (score 4):

I used `watchdog` `watchdemo` utility, it works great but for some reason the PyCharm debugger was not able to debug the subprocess spawned by `watchdemo`.

So if your project has `werkzeug` as dependency, you can use the `werkzeug._reloader.run_with_reloader` function to autoreload celery worker on code change. Plus it works with PyCharm debugger.

```py
"""
Filename: celery_dev.py
"""

import sys

from werkzeug._reloader import run_with_reloader

# this is the celery app path in my application, change it according to your project
from web.app import celery_app


def run():
    # create copy of "argv" and remove script name
    argv = sys.argv.copy()
    argv.pop(0)

    # start the celery worker
    celery_app.worker_main(argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_with_reloader(run)
```

Sample PyCharm debug configuration.

[image: PyCharm Debug Configuration]

**NOTE:**

This is a private `werkzeug` API and is working as of `Werkzeug==2.0.3`. It may stop working in future versions. Use at you own risk.

Comment: This is the one that ended up working the easiest for me, I ended up adding `werkzeug` as a dev-only dependency. One suggestion: move `from web.app import celery_app` into the `run` function so it's re-imported every reload, in case the Celery config changes at all.

Comment: In addition, `run_with_reloader()` is apparently a private API and will show a deprecation warning when used. Haven't found a replacement yet, but it's at least still working as of `werkzeug` version 2.0.3

Comment: @MicahYeager Yeah just noticed developers have added a comment to not use it. Will add disclaimer to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

There was an issue in @AlexTT answer, I don't know if I should comment on his answer of put this as an answer.

You can use watchmedo

```
pip install watchdog
```

Start celery worker indirectly via watchmedo

```
watchmedo auto-restart --directory=./ --pattern=*.py --recursive -- celery -A <app> worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO
```

Answer (score 2):

OrangeTux's solution didn't work out for me, so I wrote a little Python script to achieve more or less the same. It monitors file changes using inotify, and triggers a celery restart if it detects a `IN_MODIFY`, `IN_ATTRIB`, or `IN_DELETE`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Runs a celery worker, and reloads on a file change. Run as ./run_celery [directory]. If
directory is not given, default to cwd."""
import os
import sys
import signal
import time

import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import threading

import inotify.adapters


CELERY_CMD = tuple("celery -A amcat.amcatcelery worker -l info -Q amcat".split())
CHANGE_EVENTS = ("IN_MODIFY", "IN_ATTRIB", "IN_DELETE")
WATCH_EXTENSIONS = (".py",)

def watch_tree(stop, path, event):
    """
    @type stop: multiprocessing.Event
    @type event: multiprocessing.Event
    """
    path = os.path.abspath(path)

    for e in inotify.adapters.InotifyTree(path).event_gen():
        if stop.is_set():
            break

        if e is not None:
            _, attrs, path, filename = e

            if filename is None:
                continue

            if any(filename.endswith(ename) for ename in WATCH_EXTENSIONS):
                continue

            if any(ename in attrs for ename in CHANGE_EVENTS):
                event.set()


class Watcher(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, path):
        super(Watcher, self).__init__()
        self.celery = subprocess.Popen(CELERY_CMD)
        self.stop_event_wtree = multiprocessing.Event()
        self.event_triggered_wtree = multiprocessing.Event()
        self.wtree = multiprocessing.Process(target=watch_tree, args=(self.stop_event_wtree, path, self.event_triggered_wtree))
        self.wtree.start()
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            if self.event_triggered_wtree.is_set():
                self.event_triggered_wtree.clear()
                self.restart_celery()
            time.sleep(1)

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        self.running = False
        self.stop_event_wtree.set()
        self.celery.terminate()
        self.wtree.join()
        self.celery.wait()
        super(Watcher, self).join(timeout=timeout)

    def restart_celery(self):
        self.celery.terminate()
        self.celery.wait()
        self.celery = subprocess.Popen(CELERY_CMD)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    watcher = Watcher(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else ".")
    watcher.start()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda signal, frame: watcher.join())
    signal.pause()
```

You should probably change `CELERY_CMD`, or any other global variables.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I made it work in Django:

```py
# worker_dev.py (put it next to manage.py)
from django.utils import autoreload


def run_celery():
    from projectname import celery_app

    celery_app.worker_main(["-Aprojectname", "-linfo", "-Psolo"])


print("Starting celery worker with autoreload...")
autoreload.run_with_reloader(run_celery)
```

Then run `python worker_dev.py`. This has an advantage of working inside docker container.

Comment: This doesn't stop the old instance when reloading, as the resulting warning from celery says.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge adaptation from Suor's code.

I made a custom Django command which can be called like this:

```
python manage.py runcelery
```

So, every time the code changes, celery's main process is gracefully killed and then executed again.

Change the `CELERY_COMMAND` variable as you wish.

```py
# File: runcelery.py
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import time

import psutil
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.utils import autoreload


DELAY_UNTIL_START = 5.0
CELERY_COMMAND = 'celery --config my_project.celeryconfig worker --loglevel=INFO'


class Command(BaseCommand):

    help = ''

    def kill_celery(self, parent_pid):
        os.kill(parent_pid, signal.SIGTERM)

    def run_celery(self):
        time.sleep(DELAY_UNTIL_START)
        subprocess.run(CELERY_COMMAND.split(' '))

    def get_main_process(self):
        for process in psutil.process_iter():
            if process.ppid() == 0:  # PID 0 has no parent
                continue

            parent = psutil.Process(process.ppid())

            if process.name() == 'celery' and parent.name() == 'celery':
                return parent

        return

    def reload_celery(self):
        parent = self.get_main_process()

        if parent is not None:
            self.stdout.write('[*] Killing Celery process gracefully..')
            self.kill_celery(parent.pid)

        self.stdout.write('[*] Starting Celery...')
        self.run_celery()

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.reload_celery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution.
I am using Django 5.0 + Celery 5.2.7 on Docker.

I implemented what can be found here:
https://testdriven.io/courses/django-celery/auto-reload/

celery_worker.py -> in the management/commands/ folder of your app

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.utils import autoreload


def restart_celery():
    celery_worker_cmd = "celery -A <app> worker"
    cmd = f'pkill -f "{celery_worker_cmd}"'
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        cmd = "taskkill /f /t /im celery.exe"
    
    subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
    cmd = f'{celery_worker_cmd} -l info'
    subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd)) 


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('Starting celery worker with autoreload...')
        autoreload.run_with_reloader(restart_celery)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code

  celery:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py celery_worker
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
```

it is **very important** that the 2 volumes are the same for your web app and celery, otherwise files won't be update correctly on change.

In my case, some files i use for celery are not used by the web app.
This causes the autoreload to ignore such files. This means that with the code above, if you change a script used only by celery, it will still not trigger the autoreload.

I followed
[Django autoreload: add watched file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907285/django-autoreload-add-watched-file) .

and this is how i changed the apps file.

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.autoreload import autoreload_started

def celery_watchdog(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.watch_dir('/code/core/logic', '*.py')

class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'core'

    def ready(self):
        autoreload_started.connect(celery_watchdog)
```