# Invoke Django reload manually

Tags: django

I would like to force a reload of Django similar to when Django reloads after a file has changed. e.g. `Watching for file changes with StatReloader`

This answer has the desired result but it involves a reload on "file changing": https://stackoverflow.com/a/43593959/12446456

However, I would specifically like to invoke the reload behaviour manually after a get request has been handled by Django.

Answer (score 0):

Import `os` and `sys` and perform the load as python would initially load the django application, using:

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
```

Then in your function load the django application after you've made changes:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Main.settings')
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```